# How to change website mobile view dropdown list to a hamburger icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently working on a website template, the template shows a dropdown menu on mobile view instead of a hamburger icon, I am a backend developer, and it's a bit difficult for me to handle this, I have gone through the CSS and the js files, I didn't know what to change, any assistance would be appreciated. See the code below:

```
<div class="twelve columns">
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li>                        
                        @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")                   
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Services", "Services", "Home")
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Products", "Products", "Home")
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")
                    </li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The CSS code below:

```
    .selectnav {display: none; cursor: pointer; width: 100%; padding: 8px; height: 37px; 
    float: left; font-size: 14px;}
     #navigation {float: right;}
     #navigation ul, #navigation li {list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; 
     display:inline; }
     #navigation ul li{float:left; position:relative;}

 #navigation ul li a { 
display: inline-block;
color: #888;
padding: 31px 12px 28px 12px;
margin: 0 5px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
z-index: 1000;
position: relative;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover{
border-bottom: 3px solid #555;
}

#navigation ul ul {
opacity: 0; 
margin: -2px 0 0 5px;
filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
position: absolute;
top:-99999px; 
left: 0;
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-top: 3px solid #555;
z-index: 999;
}

#navigation ul ul li a:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#navigation ul ul li a {
padding: 8px 0;
display: block;
width: 150px;
margin: 0 16px;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 13px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#navigation ul ul ul { 
position:absolute; 
top:-99999px; 
left:100%; 
opacity: 0;
margin: -3px 0 0 0;
z-index: 999;
}

#navigation ul ul ul li a { 
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd !important;
border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#navigation ul ul li:last-child a, #navigation ul ul li:last-child a:hover {border- 
bottom: 1px solid transparent}
#navigation ul ul ul li:last-child a {border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important}
#navigation ul li:hover>ul{ opacity: 1; position:absolute; top:99%; left:0;}
#navigation ul ul li:hover>ul{ position:absolute; top:0; left:100%; opacity: 1; z- 
index:497; background: #fff border: 0; }
#navigation ul li:hover > a {color: #444;}
#navigation ul ul li:hover > a {border-top: 1px solid transparent; color: #444;}
#current {font-weight: 600 !important; color: #444 !important; border-bottom: 3px solid 
#555 !important;}
```

The Javascript code below:

```
/*!
* SelectNav.js (v. 0.1)
* Converts your <ul>/<ol> navigation into a dropdown list for small screens
*/

  window.selectnav = (function(){

 "use strict";
        
  var selectnav = function(element,options){
    
    element = document.getElementById(element);

    // return immediately if element doesn't exist  
    if( ! element) 
        return;

    // return immediately if element is not a list
    if( ! islist(element) ) 
        return;

    document.documentElement.className += " js";

    // retreive options and set defaults
    var o = options || {},
        
        activeclass = o.activeclass || 'active',
        autoselect = typeof(o.autoselect) === "boolean" ? o.autoselect : true,
        nested = typeof(o.nested) === "boolean" ? o.nested : true,
        indent = o.indent || "→",
        label = o.label || "- Navigation -",
        
        // helper variables
        level = 0,
        selected = " selected ";

    // insert the freshly created dropdown navigation after the existing navigation
    element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', parselist(element) );

    var nav = document.getElementById(id());
    
    // autoforward on click
    if (nav.addEventListener) nav.addEventListener('change',goTo);
    if (nav.attachEvent) nav.attachEvent('onchange', goTo);
    
    return nav;
    
    function goTo(e){
        
        // Crossbrowser issues - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html
        var targ;
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        if (e.target) targ = e.target;
        else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
        if (targ.nodeType === 3) // defeat Safari bug
            targ = targ.parentNode; 
    
        if(targ.value) window.location.href = targ.value; 
    }
    
    function islist(list){
        var n = list.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        return (n === 'ul' || n === 'ol');
    }
    
    function id(nextId){
        for(var j=1; document.getElementById('selectnav'+j);j++);
        return (nextId) ? 'selectnav'+j : 'selectnav'+(j-1);
    }

    function parselist(list){

        // go one level down
        level++;

        var length = list.children.length,
            html = '',
            prefix = '',
            k = level-1
            ;

        // return immediately if has no children
        if (!length) return;
    
        if(k) {
            while(k--){
                prefix += indent;
            }
            prefix += " ";
        }
        
        for(var i=0; i < length; i++){  
    
            var link = list.children[i].children[0];
            var text = link.innerText || link.textContent;      
            var isselected = '';
    
            if(activeclass){
                isselected = link.className.search(activeclass) !== -1 || 
          link.parentElement.className.search(activeclass) !== -1 ? selected : '';  
            }
    
            if(autoselect && !isselected){
                isselected = link.href === document.URL ? selected : '';
            }
            
            html += '<option value="' + link.href + '" ' + isselected + '>' + prefix + 
        text +'</option>';
    
            if(nested){
                var subElement = list.children[i].children[1];
                if( subElement && islist(subElement) ){
                    html += parselist(subElement);
                }
            }
        }
        
        // adds label
        if(level === 1 && label) html = '<option value="">' + label + '</option>' + 
   html;
    
        // add <select> tag to the top level of the list
        if(level === 1) html = '<select class="selectnav" id="'+id(true)+'">' + html + 
 '</select>';

        // go 1 level up
        level--;

        return html;
    }

};

return function (element,options) { 
    selectnav(element,options);
};



})();
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to modify the SelectNav.js 's dropdown to let it change the view when inside the mobile view?

Comment: Yes please, I want it to show the hamburger icon instead of showing a dropdown list.